# why the circularprogressBar hides when hover on the table mui react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I created a table consisting of a CircularProgressBar, when I hover the tr the CircularProgressBar's background color must change into dark blue from orange,
but I it does not change. Additionally, when the tableRow hoveres the progressBar hides and just the percentage number remain.
just material ui@5 is used

I tried to change the color by this code .MuiTableRow-root  ProgressCircular

sample source :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jgj8dh?file=package.json,src%2Findex.js

[image]

after hover

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<Box sx={{position: 'relative', zIndex: 999, display: 'inline-flex', borderRadius: "100%", ":hover CircularProgress": {backgroundColor: primary.darkBlue} }}>
  <CircularProgress thickness={2} variant="determinate" {...props}
                    sx={{color: "primary.white", borderRadius: "100%", padding: "1px", backgroundColor: primary.darkBlue,
                        "& .MuiCircularProgress-root:hover CircularProgress ": {
                            backgroundColor: `${primary.darkBlue} !important`,
                            zIndex: 999999
                        },
                    }} />
  <Box
    sx={{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      zIndex: 2,
      position: 'absolute',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderRadius: "100%",
      padding: "2px"
    }}
  >
    <Typography variant="caption" component="div" color="primary.white">
      {`${Math.round(props.value)}%`}
    </Typography>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Does this code help you?

Comment: can you check my code in stackblitz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902379/why-the-circularprogressbar-hides-when-hover-on-the-table-mui-react

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).